# Calculate the triple integral of $z^2$ limited by the functions $z=0, x^2+z=1, y^2+z=1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Calculate $$\int\int\int_D z^2 dV $$ limited by the functions
$$z=0    $$  $$ x^2+z=1; $$$$y^2+z=1$$

I am getting lost on setting the limits of integration not sure how to put the upper limit of z if I were to use dz dy dx

Comment: If you mean $z\geq 0$, then the integral is $$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{+\sqrt{1-z}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{+\sqrt{1-z}} z^2\,\rm dx~\rm dy~\rm dz$$

Comment: How did you figure out the limits of integration?